# Python Selenium Webdriver results from REST call

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Python \ Selenium \ Chrome web driver.  I have a website that I need to scrape - I can log in and create the session using selenium no problem.  I then send a REST call to retrieve all info regarding a customer i.e.:

```
driver.get('https://my_website/customerRest/show/?id=123')

print (driver.page_source)
```

At the moment it returns a large body of data with all the values I need:

[image]

How do I actually then just display the info I need from the body?  For example. There is a field called 'auditCreatedBy' in the body and I have tried the below different ways but I keep receiving the message 'unable to locate element'.  I have tried by id \ name and tag name:

```
#elementSource = driver.find_element_by_id("auditCreatedBy")
#elementSource = driver.find_element_by_name("auditCreatedBy")
elementSouce = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("auditCreatedBy")
print(elementSource)
driver.quit()
```

What am I missing?  thank you for any help and guidance - web scraping is brand new to me.

Comment: In order to help you with `#elementSource = driver.find_element_by_id("auditCreatedBy")
#elementSource = driver.find_element_by_name("auditCreatedBy")
elementSouce = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("auditCreatedBy")` we need to see the HTML of the page you are working on. Preferable from inside our own browsers.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). You may like to consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - the issue I have is the full HTML will contain sensitive data